# JavaScript for any numbered li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

I dont know if this is strange but is there any possibility to have something like this:

```
   <li id="something-1"> </li>
   <li id="something-2"> </li>
   <li id="something-3"> </li>
```

and with javascript

```
   $("#something-"+ANYNUMBER).click(function() {
    alert("Boom");
}
```

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('[id=^"something-"]').click(function() {
    alert("Boom");
});
```

But this is the situation when you need to use classes:

```
<li id="something-1" class="something"></li>
<li id="something-2" class="something"></li>
<li id="something-3" class="something"></li>
```

and select them like this:

```
$('.something').click(function() {
    alert("Boom");
});
```

In fact it will work more efficient than selecting elements by attribute selector `[id=^"something-"]`. And it's much more flexible and unobtrusive.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/RHXJb

Comment: Your welcome! I figured mind as well not answer since you already answered it, but the fiddle would still come in handy.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly with the starts-with!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the attribute [starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("li[id^=something-]")
```

or assign a class to the elements and use the class selector

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly with the starts-with!

Answer (score 1):

apply a class to all li 's

```
   <li id="something-1" class="className"> </li>
   <li id="something-2" class="className"> </li>
   <li id="something-3" class="className"> </li>

$('.className').click(function() {
    alert("Boom");
}
```

or

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert("Boom");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want every list item to `alert('boom')` when clicked, try this:

```
$('li').click(function () {
    alert("Boom");
});
```